# How Can I use nth child in react native?

Tags: react-native

How can I use nth child in react native? I need to nth-child(3) to add First View.

```
  <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={ (rowData)=>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={() => {...}>
                  <View style={{...'}}>
                    <View style={{...}}>
                      <Text style={{...'}}>{rowData.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
          }
      />
```

This is my listView and I need add marginBottom to First View(nth-child(3)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the count of index, renderRow gives the index in rowID
For ex:

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={ (rowData, sectionID, rowID, higlightRow)=>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={() => {...}>
            <View style={[rowID === 3 && {...nth-child(3)Styles}, {...otherStyles}]}>
              <View style={{...}}>
                <Text style={{...'}}>{rowData.name}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    }
/>
```

Let me know if this helps.
Working example: https://snack.expo.io/rkC_FUEUV